# how to generate string generation from keyword

Tags: string, random, cryptography, passwords, keyword

I am looking for an algorithm for string generation based on a keyword for a project I am trying to do in java.

Basically what I want to do is generate a string of characters (alphabets, numbers and symbols) meaninglessly arranged in a line in a way that one keyword produces the same string every time.

I am not sure is any algorithm exists that serves this purpose but I am looking for one.
I would like to make an algorithm that serves this purpose, for which I would like to get suggestion from the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: `base64(pbkdf2("keyword", "hoonacl", 10000, 32));` It will produce the same string everything; containing uppercase, lowercase, numbers, and a handful of symbols

Answer (score 1):

the question is ambiguous, but I'd interpret it as using the "keyword" as the seed for a PRNG which is then used to generate the output.  normally you'd use a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) to compress some arbitrary input into something suitable for a seed and then use a [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) to generate the output.  both the hash function and/or PRNG yo use could be cryptographically secure if that was important to your case

a trivial example in Python would be:

```py
from random import Random
from string import ascii_letters, digits, punctuation

# the letters we want to choose randomly from
alphabet = ascii_letters + digits + punctuation

# seed our PRNG with your keyword
keyword = 'some text'
rng = Random(keyword)

# use this freshly seeded RNG to generate some output
output = ''.join(rng.choices(alphabet, k=14))
print(output)
```

note that passing a string to `Random` in Python causes it to hash the string using SHA512 and uses the resulting bytes to seed the [MT19937 PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister).  depending on how much you care about compatibility you might want to do more yourself, but the above is enough to just get a "random looking" output from a given input.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to do symetric encryption.
There is a lot of symetric encryption algorithm.

The most simple you can use is [the caesar encryption](https://www.baeldung.com/java-caesar-cipher)
But there are a lot of other more secured algorithm like the AES. I'm not an expert, but surely a [library](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/java-security/java-aes-encryption-example/) exists in java do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You ask your question in the Cryptography section, so I assume that you need a cryptographically secure solution.  A non-crypto solution would be simpler but insecure.

You want the 'random' sequence to repeat as needed, which means that it is not really random the second and subsequent times.  That rules out cryptographic RNGs and instead indicates a stream cipher, or equivalent, which will generate a random appearing stream of bytes determined by the given key.  The obvious choice is AES in counter mode (CTR), which will repeat its output whenever you give it the same key.

You do not say exactly what set of characters you are picking from.  I will assume 62 characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9.  62 x 4 = 248, which is almost 255, the maximum value of a byte.  To avoid bias, ignore bytes in the range 248 to 255, otherwise 'a' to 'h' will be picked slightly more often than they should. Then for each byte of the AES output in the range 0 to 247 just do a MOD 62 to get the value of the character: a = 0, b = 1, etc up to 9 = 61.  If you are using a different set of characters then adjust the numbers, remembering to ignore byte values in the incomplete tail after the MOD to avoid biasing the output.

ETA: I just noticed your "and symbols".  I suggest that you add two possible symbols to bring the number of selectable characters up to 64.  That way you wont have to unbias the output bytes, just take a MOD 64.